# Arduino IDE on Android tablet

Tags: android, ide, arduino

Hi am wondering if anyone knows of a IDE for my Android tablet that I can edit compile and upload sketches to my Arduino board via USB?

Comment: What kind of Android tablet do you have?

Comment: Its a Next 10" tablet just ordered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ArduinoDroid - full-featured Arduino IDE on android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid

Answer (score 1):

Really slow response, I know but once this gets out of beta phase it could work http://codebender.cc/

Answer (score 1):

You can have Arduino IDE on android, but have some problem with the usb port

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,114141.0.html

veckoff

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but maybe you could build something like it with this?

http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can upload sketch, no root required:
http://arduinocommander.blogspot.com/2013/03/upload-sketch.html